# How to protect data during an upload on azure?

Tags: asp.net, security, azure, encryption, transfer

I'm doing an internship in Toulouse (France) and I have to create a website based on Azure in ASP.net. The website will allow users to upload pictures on the cloud. The problem is that these data are really important(medical pictures). I already know that Azure is in accordance with HIPAA so the only problem is the transfer between the website and the cloud...

Is it possible to protect these data during this step?

I've already seen that SSL could be a solution but are there existing others solutions?

Thank you for your future help.

Comment: What's wrong with SSL?

Comment: The problem with SSL is the price... So I would like to have all possibilities in order to make a choice.

Comment: What price? If you're talking about the price of the certificate, you can always generate your own self-signed certificate, or if you need it to be issued by an accepted CA, then https://www.startssl.com provide free web server certificates.

Comment: The SSL solution is probably easiest.

You could also encrypt it yourself. I would recommend any widely-used and well-audited cryptographic solution. Don't try to write your own code unless you're really paranoid and you really know what you're doing. There's jut too many easy ways to mess up crypto implementations. This also still leaves you with the issue of how to get the key to the server safely (I recommend that you just write it down and enter it by hand when you remote in)